# Firebase storage configure error on NotificationServiceExtension

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, push-notification, firebase-storage

I try to use Firebase storage in my NotificationServiceExtension.
But FIRApp.configure() does not work. Debug stops on this line but never skip to next one. Probably it throws exception.
I tried with separate GoogleService-Info.plist (with my extension bundle Id) and the same as main app plist. The same code works fine in the app. What I missed? If somebody has experience please say I have it works fine for me :). Thanks. This is my code:

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage

final class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    lazy var onceFIRConfigure: Void  = {
       FIRApp.configure()
       return
    }()

    override internal func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void){

...

       let _ = onceFIRConfigure

       // Sign In to Firebase
...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try wrapping it in a dispatch_once:

```
var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
dispatch_once(&token) {
    FIRApp.configure()
}
```

Seemed to work in my Keyboard extension (https://github.com/mcdonamp/tasty-imitation-keyboard/commit/2042a6572e3b18320dd4b4a6bb6c93e697903edf)